# How can i make a smooth scrolling effect

Tags: jquery, html, css, smooth-scrolling

Hi guys iam currently making a new portfolio and i encoutered a nice scrolling effect on the following website.
https://www.astralgameservers.com/
Does anyone know how i could make a effect like this? If so please tell me :D
I thought this was the code that made the effect but i think its wrong.

```
-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
-webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease;
-moz-backface-visibility: hidden;
-moz-transition: all 0.2s ease;
backface-visibility: hidden;
transition: all 0.2s ease;
```

I really want to know how this works

Comment: Interestingly, that site seems quite choppy when scrolling. It snaps to the content and feels wrong... at least on a MacBook trackpad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you search the script in the devtools for smoothscroll you find:

```
Plugin Name:    smoothScroll for jQuery.
Written by:     Okler Themes - (http://www.okler.net)
Version:        3.1.0
```